# Code-igniter Date to Hijri Conversion not showing result

Tags: codeigniter

I am converting current date to hijri date. Please see the link of code below which i have used in codeigniter format taken from the website in the same way but it was not showing me anything. If I have done something wrong please do let me know that also.

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
exit('No direct script access allowed');

class HijriDate extends CI_Controller{

 private $hijri;

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        //header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }

    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') { 
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
        exit(0);
    }
   // $this->load->model('HijriDateModel','hdm');
    // date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');



}

public function index($time = false)
{
    //$this->load->view('view'); 
    if(!$time) $time = time();
    $this->hijri = $this->GregorianToHijri($time);
    $result=$this->hijri;
    return json_encode($result);
   // $this->GregorianToHijri($time = null);
}
public function get_date(){
    return $this->hijri[1] . ' ' . $this->get_month_name($this->hijri[0]) . ' ' . $this->hijri[2] . 'H';
}

public function get_day(){
    return $this->hijri[1];
}

public function get_month(){
    return $this->hijri[0];
}

public function get_year(){
    return $this->hijri[2];
}

public function get_month_name($i){
    static $month  = array(
        "muharram", "safar", "rabiulawal", "rabiulakhir",
        "jamadilawal", "jamadilakhir", "rejab", "syaaban",
        "ramadhan", "syawal", "zulkaedah", "zulhijjah"
    );
    return $month[$i-1];
}

private function GregorianToHijri($time = null){
    if ($time === null) $time = time();
    $m = date('m', $time);
    $d = date('d', $time);
    $y = date('Y', $time);

    return $this->JDToHijri(cal_to_jd(CAL_GREGORIAN, $m, $d, $y));
}

private function HijriToGregorian($m, $d, $y){
    return jd_to_cal(CAL_GREGORIAN, $this->HijriToJD($m, $d, $y));
}

# Julian Day Count To Hijri
private function JDToHijri($jd){
    $jd = $jd - 1948440 + 10632;
    $n  = (int)(($jd - 1) / 10631);
    $jd = $jd - 10631 * $n + 354;
    $j  = ((int)((10985 - $jd) / 5316)) *
        ((int)(50 * $jd / 17719)) +
        ((int)($jd / 5670)) *
        ((int)(43 * $jd / 15238));
    $jd = $jd - ((int)((30 - $j) / 15)) *
        ((int)((17719 * $j) / 50)) -
        ((int)($j / 16)) *
        ((int)((15238 * $j) / 43)) + 29;
    $m  = (int)(24 * $jd / 709);
    $d  = $jd - (int)(709 * $m / 24);
    $y  = 30*$n + $j - 30;

    return array($m, $d, $y);
}

# Hijri To Julian Day Count
private function HijriToJD($m, $d, $y){
    return (int)((11 * $y + 3) / 30) +
        354 * $y + 30 * $m -
        (int)(($m - 1) / 2) + $d + 1948440 - 385;
}

}// end class Hijri Page  
?>
```

Code Details: I have made controller class in codeigniter and want only today's date in Hijri like this in json format,

```
{"hijridate":"18 Jumada al-Ukhra 1440"}
```

However it is not showing as desired. Please help me. I am not expert in codeigniter :(

Comment: We cannot tell what you have done wrong as you have not supplied any code to show what you did. But my guess is you are not displaying anything. Did you echo the date? How are you displaying it?

Comment: Share your code with your questions? @Developer'sMind

Comment: @TimBrownlaw as you can see, I have provided my code. Please take a loot at it.

Comment: @Sabbir please take a look at it. I have provided the code.

Comment: You don't have to be an expert in Codeigniter but you should know something about PHP. To avoid us guessing what you have done, can you share the code that calls this class and the code you are using to display it? This class returns a value ( a json encoded string) But what are you doing with it?

Comment: I have already shared the code above.  But it does not show the returned json string.